# How to select all rows even when count() returns nothing?

Tags: mysql

I have two simple columns for customers and orders. I want to select **all** customers and the number of appropriate orders **even** if count is zero (or null or whatever). The following ain't working and returns only customers which have orders:

```
select customers.id, count(orders.orderid) as total_orders from `xcart_customers` customers 
left join `xcart_orders` orders 
    on customers.id=orders.userid 
where orders.status in ('C', 'K') 
group by customers.id
```

Adding `having total_orders=0` does not help, because those rows were not selected. Also tried `ifnull` and many other things (left, right outer join), but no luck.

Comment: Move your where condition into the `ON`: `on customers.id=orders.userid AND orders.status in ('C','K')` Otherwise that WHERE clause causes your query to act like an inner join.

Comment: If you want all rows, remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks guys, I do not get it, but it works. Couldn't find the answer on the net, you can answer below, so it may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Query.

```
select customers.id, count(orders.orderid) as total_orders from `xcart_customers` customers 
left join `xcart_orders` orders 
    on customers.id=orders.userid and orders.status in ('C', 'K') 
group by customers.id
```